# Referrential integrity in Liferay 6.2 service builder

Tags: mysql, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-ide, liferay-aui

I have been searching around for setting up referrential integrity for my database using Liferay IDE's service builder.

For e.g: I have a master table(entity) and a child table(entity). child table has a foreign key which is the primary key for the master table. If I delete one entry in the master table, the respective row in the child table should also get deleted. How can I achieve this in Liferay Service Builder.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no such provisions in liferay service builder, you manually have to write code for removing child table data

Comment: Forget it. Do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, Service Builder neither provides that nor is supposed to work with such database checks. In the Service Builder design, your *services* should delete dependent entities. In your example, the service which manages the master table should, on its `delete` method, delete also the child rows pointing to the deleting master row. A good example of this is the [`JournalArticleLocalServiceImpl.deleteArticle(JournalArticle, String, ServiceContext)`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portlet/journal/service/impl/JournalArticleLocalServiceImpl.java#L925-1064) method, which does, for example, this:

```
journalArticleImageLocalService.deleteImages(
    article.getGroupId(), articleId, article.getVersion());

// Expando

expandoRowLocalService.deleteRows(article.getId());
```